# Wordpress custom routing and custom functionality

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on WordPress website which require some custom functionality. I have post which are actually a product. I have added custom fields to insert specification of those products. I want to create dynamic specification page for each product. For ex.

Product url: http://www.example.com/product-1.html

Specification of the product: http:///www.example.com/spec/product-1.html

So how can I create a custom route that will fetch 'product-1' and render 'spec.php' template. I found this post [Custom url route](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes) which explains custom routing. But I also want to fetch the post from database and also want to set other variables which are set for regular post.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation just create a Costum post type.

see the link below for reference:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

Comment: That would work but. I want to enter all data on one page and automate rest. Creating multiple custom posts for large number of posts is not efficient for me. If I had to change something of one post then same changes would need to be done on all dependent custom posts.